# Como exibir um menu de acordo com o tipo de usuário logado com Ionic / Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, localstorage

Olá, tenho dois tipos de usuários: comprador e vendedor.

Como exibir um menu de acordo com o tipo de usuário logado com Ionic / Angularjs?

Atualmente, e não funciona bem, estou colocando em cada item do menu um ng-show:

```
ng-show="permissaoUser"
```

E no Controller do Menu faço:

```
if($window.localStorage.getItem("user_cod_cliente") === null){
            $scope.permissaoUser = false;
        }else{
            $scope.permissaoUser = true;
        }      

        if($window.localStorage.getItem("global_fornecedor") === null){
           $scope.permissaoVovo = false;
        }else{
            $scope.permissaoVovo = true;
        }
```

Ou seja, pego a informação salva em meu LocalStorage após o login.

Acontece que o menu só apresenta de acordo com o usuário SE der F5 no NAVEGADOR que é onde acompanho o desenvolvimento.

POREM, no emulador ou no aparelho não funciona.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Por que não envia esses menus, em forma de vetor, pro seu aplicativo. Depois, cria uma diretiva que monta o menu conforme esse vetor. Acredito que tratar isso no backend seria mais sensato e mais facil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude para uma função da seguinte forma:

```
ng-show="checarPermissoes('cliente')"
```

ou
    ng-show="checarPermissoes('cliente')"

E a função:

```
$scope.verificarPermissoes(tipo) {
  var permitido;

  if (tipo === 'cliente' && $window.localStorage.getItem("user_cod_cliente") !== null) {
    permitido = true;
  } else if (tipo === 'fornecedor' && $window.localStorage.getItem("global_fornecedor") !== null) {
    permitido = true;
  } else {
    permitido = false;
  }

  return permitido;
}
```

Comment: De notar que só isso nao impede que o utilizador mal intencionado veja essa parte do site; Tente também fazer um check, do lado do servidor, quando os users fizerem acçoes apartir desta página para garantir que quem acede à API é quem voce pensa que é

Comment: @MoshMage na realidade o ideal, além do que você sugeriu, é fazer essa verificação no registro dos `states` e só disponibiliza-los caso o usuário tenha permissão

Comment: Resolvido com a dica do @Sorack

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack :)

Comment: @Ramos não esqueça de marcar a resposta como resolução clicando no ✅ do lado esquerdo da resposta para que possa ser usada por outros usuários